# How to access the setup wizard on Sonicwall TZ 100 firewall

Tags: networking, router, firewall, lan

I am trying to setup a TZ 100 firewall. I am following [these instructions](http://apetec.com/support/TZ200-Setup.htm) and I have attempted to follow these instructions:

"Connect your computer to the LAN (X0) port on the SonicWALL. Connect an ethernet cable from the WAN (X1) port on the SonicWALL to the LAN port on your internet router or modem."

So currently, I have X0 going to my computer and X1 going a LAN port on my router. I also tried connecting to my modem. However, after then trying to load the configuration page, 192.168.168.168, it will not load nor will it ping.

I have tried the manual reset button (currently, there is an indicator light with a wrench blinking on the firewall) as well. I have also tried pinging 192.168.168.168 to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

I have also referred to the getting started guide, which so far, doesn't have much information beyond the linked page. I have ensured DHCP addressing is configured on my computer as it suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try manually assigning your computer an ip address on the 192.168.168.0/24 network.  Then you should be able to access the configuration interface at `http://192.168.168.168`.

If the device was previously configured, you'll need to reset the device by holding in the reset button on the back with a paper clip.  Hold for 30 seconds or until the config LED starts flashing.

Comment: Currently, the config LED is flashing. How do I manually assign my computer an IP address in this network?

Comment: Search '<your O/S> static ip' for instructions.  In windows, it's in the Network and Sharing Center in the Control Panel.

Answer (score -3):

SonicWall acts as DHCP server which should assign an IP address to your PC.

You need to check what IP address is getting assigned to your PC by the SonicWall. If you get nothing, then something is wrong with your settings/cable/SonicWall. Reset the SonicWall again and check your cable and your PC's settings to make sure it's still DHCP.

If you see an IP from another subnet, then just check your DHCP server and point your browser there. If you are on Windows, you can find your DHCP server by doing `ipconfig /all` and looking for `DHCP server`.